# clogitL1 - extract regression coefficients

Tags: r, conditional-statements, logistic-regression, coefficients, regularized

I'm an R newbie.  I'm using "clogitL1" to run a regularized conditional logistic regression for a matched case-control study with 1021 independent variables (metabolites). I'm not able to extract the regression coefficients.  I've tried `summary(x)`, `coef(x)`, `coefficient(x)`, `x$beta` - none of them work. I'm able to run it OK, and if I follow it with "cv.clogitL1" I can extract the cross-validated estimated coefficients, but not the estimated coefficients for the original model.  Here's some of my code:

```
strata=sort(data.meta$MATCHED_NEW)
condlog <- clogitL1(y=data.meta$BCR, x=data.meta$ln_metab[, data.features ], strata,
  numLambda=100, minLambdaRatio=0.000001, alpha = 1.0)
```

"strata" is a vector indicating pairing of cases & controls.
"data.meta$BCR" is a vector inicating case or control status
"data.meta$ln_metab" is a matrix with observations as rows and metabolite levels as columns
"data.features" is a vector indicating which metabolites passed several dimension reduction filters.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Are you literally typing summary(x) instead of summary(condlog )?

Comment: No - I'm typing summary(condlog) -  should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found your question while I was looking for similar answers and after reading a bit from the clogitL1 helpfile and googling some random stuff on the internet this is what I have pieced together. I hope it helps someone. The output of the clogitL1 function that you ran, is the results of running your model multiple times with different values of lambda (a penalty parameter on your predictors). But now you need to run the second part, the cross validation step, to help you make the decision of which lambda to choose.

Adding:

```
condlog_cv = cv.clogitL1(condlog)
```

will run the cross validation.

```
plot(condlog_cv)
```

will produce a nice figure that shows how you deviance changes as you change lambda. What you're looking for is the value of lambda that minimizes the deviance (i.e. doesn't change the overall "performance" *loosely* of the model even though you dropped predictors). However, there are probably several values of lambda that may *more or less* perform about the same (that's what's shown with the error bars) so what we really want is the value of lambda corresponding to the fewest predictors (and hence the more parsimonious model) within a tolerance of the "best" (i.e. lowest deviance) model. Typically, this is the 1 standard deviation rule meaning that any value of lambda that produces a deviance within 1 standard deviation of the "best" model, is equally good (and therefore better if the value of lambda corresponds to fewer predictors). These are what is shown between the vertical bars.

You can then use your model summary to extract the value of lambda and the coefficients of the final model corresponding to either the absolute minimum conditional deviance or the lambda corresponding to the smallest change of conditional deviance within 1 SD.

```
# absolute minimum
summary(condlog_cv)$beta_minCV

# fewest # of non-zero predictors that performs essentially the same
summary(condlog_cv)$beta_minCV1se
```

The output will not be labeled but will correspond to the values you put into the model (i.e. position 1 will be the beta coefficient corresponding to your data feature 1).

I hope I did ok, I'm learning myself.